# Aide Does not Write aide.db After Successful Scan

Tags: configuration, aide

I have installed aide on Ubuntu 22.04 and left the default configuration.
After it ran, I got an email report that indicates that everything went smooth. See the report below.
The `/var/lib/aide/aide.db.new` and `/var/lib/aide/aide.db` are zero bytes.
There's plenty free space on the device and I can't find anything unusual in the log files.

Any ideas how to search for the cause of that issue?

```
AIDE returned with exit code 1. Added entries detected!


AIDE produced no errors.

******************************************************************************
*    AIDE has returned long output which has been truncated in this mail     *
******************************************************************************
Output is 2792556 lines, truncated to 1000.
Start timestamp: 2023-08-20 06:25:01 +0200 (AIDE 0.17.4)
AIDE found differences between database and filesystem!!
New AIDE database written to /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new
Ignored e2fs attributes: EIh

Summary:
  Total number of entries:      2792523
  Added entries:                2792500
  Removed entries:              0
  Changed entries:              0
```

Comment: You haven't specified how did you run `aide`.  The default action is just a check, without updating the db.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The packaged version adds a script in `/etc/cron.daily/`. I have the packaged version on several servers and all others work like expected (i.e. writes the aide.db.new).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, you need to run `aideinit` to create the new database after installing `aide` package.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I ran `aideinit` but after that, I fired a maintenance script, that copies aide.db.new over aide.db -- while aide was running. That more or less destroys the database and makes it necessary to run `aideinit` again.